# Why isn't the copy or move constructor called C++

Tags: c++

```
struct Foo {
    Foo(): { cout << "Default Ctor" << endl; }
    Foo(const Foo& foo) { cout << "Copy Ctor" << endl; }
    Foo(Foo&& foo) { cout << "Move Ctor" << endl; }
};

Foo test() {
    Foo temp;
    return temp;
}

int main() {
    Foo f1;           // Default Ctor
    Foo f2(f1);       // Copy Ctor
    Foo f3(test());   // ????
    return 0;
}
```

The `f3` object is successfully created, but neither copy constructor nor move constructor is called.

How does this work?

Comment: `f3` is created *in situ*.

Comment: f3 does call the move constructor

Comment: @doug But cout in the move constructor does not be called

Comment: Curious. It does for me. What compiler are you using?

Comment: @doug I use GNU++17 in xcode

Comment: You should edit your question and copy and paste exactly what the output is. I get "Default Ctor, Copy Ctor, Default Ctor, Move Ctor." Which is what I expect from your code.